# Recursively remove empty items in tree directory structure

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, recursion, iteration, nsoutlineview

I have created a directory tree structure of files and folders using [NSTreeNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTreeNode_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) which I show in a NSOutlineView. My problem is that some folders are empty and I would like to remove these from being shown. I have tried recursively to iterate through each element of the tree structure to remove elements, but it is clearly much easier to build a tree than to tear it down. My iterations have started at root and then I iterate through each nodes childnodes until I reach the top of the tree. However, as some folders can contain several empty and non-empty folders it becomes difficult to efficiently remove elements I am not certain are emtpy. Just because a folder only contains another folder does not mean I can remove it as child folders may eitehr be empty or contain files.

I think I need to find the top element/directory of the tree and then iterate backwards towards to my rootnode through all of the parents childnodes and check if each folder is empty. If a folder is empty or only contain the folder I am currently in, remove the folder and the parent folder, and so on until I reach root.

However, I am unable to get this to work.  Does anybody have a method to find the elements defining the top of the tree? Or is there a good way to sort/remove empty elements in a NSTreeNode structure?

I appreciate all the help I can get on this. Thanks. Cheers, Trond

Comment: I would think that you just need to traverse to the end of each branch and if the last folder is empty remove it, then recursively move up the tree removing folders that are empty and are leaves...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudo code:

```
BOOL removeTheChildless(NSTreeNode *tree)
{
   for each NSTreeNode *child
   {
      if ( removeTheChildless(child) )
          removeChild child from tree
   }

   return tree.isLeaf;
}
```

The "for each" can be based on `mutableChildNodes`. HTH.